# Extract Claims from an Encrypted SAML 1 Assertion Returned from WS-Federation

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, saml, adfs, ws-federation

Our SSO implementation successfully extracts SAML claims from assertions obtained from SAML responses (SAML 2.0) posted from IDPs. We are now trying to support WS-Federation in support of applications that are not browser-based (e.g. native mobile app), and are attempting to use the same code to extract the claims from the assertion token returned by WS-Fed.

We’ve had to generalize our code a bit (outlined below) since at least AD FS returns SAML 1.1 for such requests rather than 2.0. It works well for unencrypted tokens but I’m not able to make it work when encryption is involved.

Here’s a typical SAML 2.0 assertion (extracted from the SAML response):

```
<EncryptedAssertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"> <xenc:EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">...</xenc:EncryptedData></EncryptedAssertion>
```

An unencrypted SAML 1 token returned from WS-Fed (also works):

```
<saml:Assertion MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1" AssertionID="…" Issuer="…" IssueInstant="2018-02-07T19:53:54.162Z" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion">…</saml:Assertion>
```

And here’s an encrypted token (breaks):

```
<xenc:EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" />…</xenc:EncryptedData>
```

When this latest one is served to `tokenHandler.ReadToken`, I get an “expected assertion element” error. I tried to wrap the `EnctypedData` element with an XML Assertion but of course it doesn’t work as the root node already is the assertion, and in any case the SAML 1 handler doesn’t seem to handle `EncryptedData`.

Here’s the code that makes the WS-Federation call and then calls to extract claims:

```
private SamlInfo AuthenticateGetSamlInfo(string username, string password) {
    // Use WS-Federation to get a token
    SecurityToken token = GetToken(username, password, relyingParty);
    GenericXmlSecurityToken genericXmlToken = token as GenericXmlSecurityToken;
    if (genericXmlToken != null) {
        SamlInfo returnedSamlInfo = new SamlInfo(); // Info extracted from SAML

        samlProcessor.ExtractSamlClaimsFromAssertionXml(
            genericXmlToken.TokenXml.OuterXml, returnedSamlInfo);
        return returnedSamlInfo;
    }
    return null;
}
```

And here’s the code to extract the claims:

```
private void ExtractSamlClaimsFromAssertion(XmlReader reader, SamlVersion samlVersion,
    SamlInfo samlInfo) {
    // On entry reader is positioned on the Assertion element.
    // Partner (IDP) certificates are stored in the TrustedPeople store, as well as our
    // private encryption certificate.
    var tokenHandlerConfig = new SecurityTokenHandlerConfiguration();
    SecurityTokenResolver tokenResolver = new X509CertificateStoreTokenResolver(
        StoreName.TrustedPeople, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
    tokenHandlerConfig.ServiceTokenResolver = tokenResolver;
    tokenHandlerConfig.IssuerTokenResolver = tokenResolver;
    tokenHandlerConfig.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.ChainTrust;
    tokenHandlerConfig.TrustedStoreLocation = StoreLocation.LocalMachine;
    tokenHandlerConfig.AudienceRestriction.AllowedAudienceUris.Add(new Uri(relyingPartyUri));

    // Load partner issuer certificates from TrustedPeople store. 
    var issuerNameRegistry = tokenHandlerConfig.IssuerNameRegistry as ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry;
    if (issuerNameRegistry != null) {
        SsoPartnersStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in SsoPartnersStore.Certificates)
            if (!issuerNameRegistry.ConfiguredTrustedIssuers.ContainsKey(cert.Thumbprint))
                issuerNameRegistry.AddTrustedIssuer(cert.Thumbprint, cert.Issuer);
    }

    SecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = CreateSamlTokenHandler(samlVersion);
    tokenHandler.Configuration = tokenHandlerConfig;
    SecurityToken assertionToken = tokenHandler.ReadToken(reader);

    if (samlVersion == SamlVersion.v1) {
        SamlAssertion assertion = (assertionToken as SamlSecurityToken).Assertion;

        // ... Read claims from assertion statements
    }
    else {  // SAML 2.0
        Saml2Assertion assertion = (assertionToken as Saml2SecurityToken).Assertion;

        // ... Read claims from assertion statements
    }
}
```

How do we make it work with encrypted SAML 1 assertions? Is there another approach we can take?